# javascript xpath - get element value and its position, and save results in object array

Tags: javascript, xpath

I have a markup resembling the following (note: the spans are optional child elements):

```
<li class="prices">
   11.11
   <span>1.11</span>
</li>
<li class="prices">
    22.22
</li>
<li class="prices">
   33.33
   <span>3.33</span>
</li>
<li class="prices">
   44.44
</li>
<li class="prices">
   55.55
   <span>5.55</span>
</li>
```

I want to return a list of prices within the spans AND its position in an object array, so I get something like:  { pos: 0, price, 1.11 }, { pos: 2, price, 3.33 }, { pos: 4, price, 5.55 }  What's the JS code to do that?  :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a container element which contains all your li.prices elements:

```
var container = document.getElementById("container");
var arr = [];
for (var pos = 0; pos < container.children.length; pos++) {
    var li = container.children[pos];
    var spans = li.getElementsByTagName("span");
    var price = spans.length > 0 ? spans[0].innerHTML : "";
    arr.push({pos: pos, price: price});
}
```

This will store the price as a string and it will use an empty string if there is no span element inside a li element.

Comment: sorry, I'm looking for an xpath solution, and the only assumption I can make is that the two prices shares the same parent node.

Answer (score 0):

You will at least need XPath 2.0 to do this.

For getting a string representation like you proposed, use for example

```
string-join(
  for $li at $position in //li
  return concat("{ pos: ", $position, ", price: ", $li/span/data(), " }")[$li/span]
, ', ')
```

If you prefer an array, you could return everything in a sequence and read odd/even pairs from it in JavaScript:

```
for $li at $position in //li
return ($position, $li/span/data())[$li/span]
```

Comment: tried this and it doesn't work, maybe I'm not using it right:    xpath = 'string-join(for $li at $position in return concat("{ pos: ", $position, ", price: ", $li/span/data(), " }")[$li/span], ", ")';

  var xPathResult = document.evaluate(xpath, document, null, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE, null);

Comment: Well, as I wrote, you will need at least XPath 2.0. I'm not sure which browsers offer that or what you can do to execute it anyway. You could try [XQIB](http://www.xqib.org/) which supports XPath 2.0 as a subset of XQuery 1.0 if you insist on an XPath solution.